# Will Apple replace my MacBook Pro’s logic board if a third-party person repaired it?

Tags: macbook-pro, repair, logicboard

I got some moisture damage on my M1 MacBook Pro that I bought last year (there’s a greenish spot on the logic board). A third-party local repair shop says that the moisture spot is in a place where the voltage difference isn’t very high and it can be repaired (for much less than the cost of replacing the entire board). My question is — if this person tries to repair it but it doesn’t work, can I still bring the MacBook Pro to Apple and ask them to replace the entire logic board with a brand new one?

Can they just refuse to replace the board if they think it’s been touched by a third-party repair shop? I know my warranty gets voided, but outside the warranty, can the entire official Apple repair service get voided?

Really nervous, so I’d appreciate a response a lot!

Comment: Define 'moisture damage'. Liquid on the circuitry is almost always a major problem, that will shorten the life of the Mac.

Comment: @benwiggy There's a green spot on the logic board. The MacBook hasn't been powering on, and it doesn't take in charge (the indicator on the charging cable doesn't light up). Wdym by shorten the life of the mac -- if I replace the entire logic board, this shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: How did it happen? Yes, if the logic board is replaced, it will be fine.

Comment: Water damage negates any warranty anyway. There are Liquid Contact Indicators in Macs. If they're triggered, no warranty - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201880

Answer (score 0):

The warranty concerns problems with the device for which Apple is responsible (and for which Apple is then legally obliged to repair at their cost). Apple would not do it for free if it's been tampered with.

Apple's warranty does not cover accidental damage, so you would have to pay to have it repaired anyway. I can't see why Apple would refuse to do the work and charge you for it.

Comment: Yeah I don't have AppleCare+, and my warranty won't apply anyway, so I need the paid repair costs from what I understand. Do you have a guess for the total $ damage I'll have to pay? (for an entire M1, 1TB, 16GB RAM logic board)

I'm concerned about Apple refusing because some websites online say that they sometimes refuse if they see that the product has been 'internally tampered with'.

Comment: @kushal we don't have the Apple pricing structure. If you are now focusing on price then that puts this question off-topic.

Comment: @kushal Read my reply again -- and read exactly what "some websites" say. They are talking about Apple honouring the warranty, which means Apple paying for the repair. If you are paying for the repair, Apple don't care what you've done to it. The logic board on my Mini was about £400 to replace.